# Break table which inside table but keeping rows untouch

Tags: html, css, pdf-generation, dompdf, page-break

I have the following HTML> [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dPZW4/).
When I output it to PDF using DOMPDF, on the first page I got the 2 first rows, than I got 10 empty pages and than 2 pages with the rest of the content.

How can I break the table so it will spread on the correct number of pages?
I tried to use `page-break-inside: avoid;` on the main table, but It ruined the broken row.

[image]

I want it to break like  you expect it to break but I have no idea how...

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Do you know where to break your page? I mean these rows can increase or they'll be fixed always?

Comment: They'll always be fixed... I dont know where to break thats why I asked..

Comment: You are saying they'll be fixed so you should know where to break right?

Comment: I think I should break the row (if necessary) > page-break-before:auto, If I am right.. but It didnt work

Comment: No try this see if it works, this is not recommended but atleast you can try.. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bvBS5/1/)

Comment: Didnt work, or I am using it wrong ~dont think so~

Comment: You can try it here http://eclecticgeek.com/dompdf/docs_0-6-0/demo.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rendering issue is due to a known bug related to a single entity that is too large to fit on a page. In your case, your product list table (which is larger than a page) is contained within another table, which creates a table cell too large to fit on a page. See the dompdf tracker, [issue 91: dompdf unable to split table cells between pages](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/issues/detail?id=91).

Luckily, your layout is such that the work around is fairly simple. Move the product list table outside the container. [I updated your original jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dPZW4/1/).

Comment: It partially works > The page breaks fine but the last row in the broken page is missing the bottom border, any Idea why?

Comment: Are you using the jsfiddle that I updated, or do you have a new document I can look at?

Comment: Here's the new http://jsfiddle.net/dPZW4/2/ I figured that the border-collapse cause it but I couldnt fix it...

Comment: Hm ... the last product row? Seems ok when I test: http://eclecticgeek.com/dompdf/debug.php?identifier=7e37741572c400c85bcec06bd4f3bf3b

Comment: Did you change anything? because for me, the border of the last row in each page {if page breaks}, disappear... *You are using letter format, thats why... use A4

Comment: Still not seeing it. I've tried a few different page sizes. Which version of dompdf are you on? You might try refreshing the files (or even [downloading the latest code](http://eclecticgeek.com/dompdf)).

Comment: Downloaded lastest version (which I am pretty sure thats what I used before), and still the same... urs contain 12 rows on the first page and my contains 13 rows... one of us is using different settings ~I didnt touch the settings~, your source code contains extenral css such as normalize...

Comment: I was using the jsfiddle "show" frame for render, which must toss in some extra CSS. But even if use a version without a link to that CSS I'm not seeing the problem. Can you post your PDF so I can see how it's rendering?

Comment: I tried to use ur debugger and for some reason it worked, except that it didnt show the images - the might be the cause for the problem. anyway, here you can see both html and pdf http://sandsenterprises.co.uk/new-design/wish-list-test.php

Comment: I'm at a bit of a loss. There must be some difference in our systems that's causing the problem, but I don't see what. What OS & version of PHP are you using? And the images not loading ... I dunno. I didn't have any problems when I used the jsfiddle document.

Comment: I am using Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/0.9.8r DAV/2 PHP/5.3.8 (Darwin OS). How did the images load? maybe I used wrong options? (I used A4, portrait, 96 DPI, trunk, load file via > tried all the options. Also tried to load via remote & manual, but still the images didnt load).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14707/discussion-between-brians-and-ron)

Comment: hi I am also having this issue I checked the link http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/issues/detail?id=91 but its not working anymore please can you tell me solution

Comment: Tables are still a problem, issues can now be found on github. That particular one is [#98](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/98)